# TRttiField.GetValue does not give the correct value

Tags: delphi, rtti

I'm on Delphi 10.3.

```pascal
TTestRTTI = class
  field1: integer;
end;

procedure testRTTI();
var
  field : TRttiField;
  fields: TArray<TRttiField>;
  testInstance: TTestRTTI;
  val: Integer;
begin
  testInstance := TTestRTTI.Create();
  testInstance.field1 := 5;
  fields := TRttiContext.Create().GetType(TypeInfo(TTestRTTI)).GetFields();
  for field in fields do begin
    val := field.GetValue(@testInstance).AsInteger;
  end;
  // val is not 5 ?
  OutputDebugString(PChar(val.ToString()));
end;
```

It seems GetValue does not return the correct information. What am I doing wrong ?

Edit : It seems that Delphi returns a Long instead of an Integer ? Is this a platform problem ? I'm on Windows 10 64 bits.[image]

Answer (score 2):

The `TRttiField.GetValue()` function requires passing in a pointer to an instance to get the value of a field of that instance. However, your instance is an object and the reference to the object is already a pointer so you should pass it directly, instead of retrieving the address of the pointer itself.

Change the following line and remove the `@` operator from the call:

```
val := field.GetValue(testInstance).AsInteger;
```

---

On the other hand, if your `TTestRTTI` would be a `record` instead of a `class`, then you would indeed need to use the `@` operator when passing record instance to the `GetValue` function:

```
TTestRTTI = record
  field1: integer;
end;

var testInstance: TTestRTTI;

val := field.GetValue(@testInstance).AsInteger;
```

Answer (score 1):

Okay so my problem with that I was passing the address of `testInstance` directly to `GetValue()`. Since `testInstance` is a class, that doesn't work.

Problem is, when working with generics, passing either one doesn't work. So instead of having a generic procedure like:

```pascal
procedure TMyClass.DoStuff<T>(a: T);
```

You need :

```pascal
procedure TMyClass.DoStuff<T>(a: Pointer);
```

And then you can pass `a` directly to `PByte` or `GetValue`.

Comment: Related: [Are pointers to generic types supported in Delphi XE?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4635945/) and [Howto cast pointer to generic parameter type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/511247/)

Comment: `testInstance` is not a class but an instance (or an object) of a class.